# A proper Git workflow for svn to git

Tags: git, svn

Suppose we've got two teams : TeamA and TeamB.
TeamA maintains the historical project "ProjectA" with **subversion**, and TeamB forked projectA months ago to create "ProjectB" which is maintained under **Git**.
In reality, ProjectB is ProjectA + some additionnal directories and files, and must stay that way. So, regularly, TeamB have to synchronise ProjectB with ProjectA (let's say, every month when ProjectA is considered as "stable" enough), that is to say that all commits of ProjectA must be replayed over ProjectB.

(In the long term, ProjectA will be abandonned and ProjectB will become the main project.)

What would be a proper way to regularly report all trunk svn commits toward the ProjectB git master branch? *I will never need to perform the reverse operation (Git => SVN is out of scope).*
Currently, I use git-svn to cherry pick the range of commits of the last month of ProjectA and apply them to ProjectB's master branch.
But it requires to search for the last SVN commit I applied last month in order to cherry pick the good range of commits.

I was wondering if instead of a cherry pick, I could use a persistent Git mirror of the Subversion repo, and use a simple svn merge every month or something like that.

Any idea of a usual workflow for that?

Comment: Can't you just pull A into some branch, work on B in another and regularly perform a plain old merge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A persistent git mirror of the svn repo is exactly what I would do.  It doesn't have to be a separate repository from the ProjectB repo, though -- just have a single branch which corresponds exactly to ProjectA's svn repo, and use `git svn rebase` to update it periodically.  (Despite the name, `git svn rebase` is basically just a pull, as long as you don't commit anything to that branch yourself.)  Then use normal git tools like `git merge` to get the stuff from that branch into your ProjectB development branch(es).

Comment: Thanks, the Git single branch for the svn mirror is a better idea! Thereforce, I wonder if I can use anything else than a cherry picking operation since merge ou rebase from the "svn" branch generate a lot of conflict... => all modifications made in ProjectB on common files seem to be conflicting with the ones in ProjectA :( I just want to add the differences from a specific subversion revision number (about 3 months ago).